# Prevent Excel file from auto-formatting the date

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

I am using OLEDB to insert date in format "yyyy-MM-dd" to a cell belong to a column in an excel sheet. But, the Excel sheet kept formatting it to "MM/dd/yyy".

How can I insert exactly "yyyy-MM-dd" to excel and prevent it from changing?

Below is an example of how I insert the date to column 2.

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + filename + "';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;");
con.Open();

string insertStatement = @"INSERT INTO [sheet1$] ([F1], [F2]) VALUES (?, ?)";
OleDbCommand insertCommand;
insertCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertStatement, con);
string text = "abc";
string date = "2016-08-29";
insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[F1]", text);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[F2]", date ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: how did you create the sheet? format the column as text instead of general, if you can

Comment: when I format the sheet as "text" then I won't able to see the date. I will see it as an integer. For example, instead of seeing "2016-08-29" I will then see 42611.

Comment: That usually only happens with actual date columns...

Comment: I have tested it with text formatted columns and it works fine

Comment: Note that the column must be formatted as text FIRST - once there is a date in there, Excel helpfully converts it to a number, as you have seen

Comment: Yup me too. However, given that the excel file already has thousands of rows of data I cannot just change the column format to "text". Is there a way to do it in code to force it not change the format?

Comment: How is the column currently formatted; General, or Date?

Comment: it is format to Date

Comment: I found a work around by changing the Regional and Language Options in control panel. But this isn't ideal.

Comment: That was about all I found, too.

Comment: thank you for your help. appreciate that.

Comment: You know, you CAN just change the format to text even for existing columns, it just takes a few minutes. Excel has a neat little feature, called Text To Columns, that I've abused for that purpose before. Assuming it's your sheet and you have the rights to do that and all. You could also just copy the values as text into a new column and move the new column back to where it was. Depends on how much you want to mess with it.